# "Configuring hive with derby"

Tags: hive, derby, hadoop2

**hive-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true</value>
  <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</value>
  <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
<value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>
<description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
</property>
```

**[user1@slave3 ~]$ hive**

```
which: no hbase in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin:/home/user1/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/user1/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/bin:/usr/local/derby/bin:/home/user1/.local/bin:/home/user1/bin:usr/local/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_161/bin:/home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/sbin:/home/user1/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/user1/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/bin:/usr/local/derby/bin)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user1/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/user1/hadoop-2.9.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/home/user1/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/hive-common-2.3.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
```

**hive> show databases;**

```
FAILED: SemanticException org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iK0z.png)

I'm trying to install hive, but it gives SemanticException. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the metastore? Your metastore must be up and running before running the queries on hive.

run the below command to create the metastore db

schematool -dbType derby -initSchema

then start the metastore

hive --service metastore &

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, it is just because of two SLF4j are running but java uses only a single mandatory dependency so you just need to delete on of this file.
I delete this from my hive and it just worked.

All you have to do is, delete this file

> log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!

from

> /home/user1/apache-hive-2.3.2-bin/lib/

and you are good to go.